# How to implement a "back" action in a QWebView/QWebPage

Tags: qt, pyqt, qwebview, qwebpage

I have a simple widget that is a QWebView. I load it with setHtml(). Most of the time this is just so the user can read the styled text, however there are a few links, and if one is clicked, the QWebView properly displays the linked page, but now there is no way to get back to the original page. I want to implement a Back key shortcut (or maybe a Back button, but the problem is the same). And I can't figure out how to tell my QWebView or its QWebPage to do that. Some code trying everything I could think of:

```
class helpDisplay(QWebView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None ):
        super(helpDisplay, self).__init__(parent)
        self.backAction = self.page().action(QWebPage.Back)
        self.backAction.setEnabled(True) # initially was False
        self.backAction.setShortcut(QKeySequence.Back) # was empty, now ctl-[
        ...
        self.setHtml(...) # big string input from a file
    ...
    def keyPressEvent(self, event): # trap keys
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_B: # temporary for testing
            self.page().triggerAction(QWebPage.Back)
            self.backAction.activate(QAction.Trigger)
```

None of this causes navigation backward from a link. Hitting ctl-[ does nothing. Hitting "b" enters the keyPressEvent trap and calls triggerAction and activate, but nothing visible happens.

Edit: found WebPage.history(), and added the following to the key-b trap:
                self.page().history().back()
This kinda works: if I click a link start->A, `self.page().history().canGoBack()` is False and `self.page().history().back()` does nothing. However if I click another link start->A->B, *now* it canGoBack() and does, back to page A. But I can't go back to the original page loaded with setHtml().

Conclusion: WebView.setHtml() does not create an entry in WebPage.history. This could explain why backAction doesn't seem to work...

Further edit: Following up in the Qt Assistant I find that under QWebFrame.setHtml() it admits, "Note: This method will not affect session or global history..." Unfortunately they didn't carry that note back to QWebPage or QWebView. In fact it makes sense: a history item would normally be just a URL, so it isn't too odd they wouldn't want to store 20K or 50K of html text as a history item.

Answer (score 1):

Just to reduce some of your code, QWebView does have a back() slot: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qwebview.html#back.

That aside, since you have discovered that the use of setHtml() apparently doesn't create a history entry, you could try one of these suggestions:

Use your history check to see if it can go back. If it can, go back. If it can't run setHtml again with your original source since you know it was the first page displayed.

Or, write your pages out to a temp html file and use the load() method instead for a file:/// url. That might make a history entry.

Comment: Ooh, how did I miss that? Oh, back() is in the list of slots, not members. Says it's the same as `view->page()->triggerPageAction(QWebPage::GoBack);` which is basically what I was trying to do (except, there's no "GoBack" action name, only "Back").

Comment: Anyway, thanks. I was working my way around to your solution: keep the setHtml string around, and reload it when history is empty. Actually could track the linkClicked signal to know a link had been followed, and thus know not to do a needless reload if the back key is hit extra times. But I will also explore your temp file idea too.